# pass value from Jframe to another Jframe then pass to another JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have `login.java` then i need to pass the username from the login.java to `nursepage.java` then pass one more time to `updatestatus.java` so how do i pass the value for three times?

Comment: this mey help (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834915/how-to-pass-a-variable-value-from-one-jframe-to-another-jframe-in-netbeans)

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you simply could use some kind of static method-call-chain. e.g.

**Updatestatus.java**

```
private String username;

public static void setUsername(String username){
    this.username = username;
}
```

**Nursepage.java**

```
import Updatestatus;

public static void setUsername(String username){
    Updatestatus.setUsername(username);
}
```

**Login.java**

```
import Nursepage;

private String username;

private static void provideUsername(){
   Nursepage.setUsername(username);
}
```

Set your username locally in Login.java, then call the provideUsername()-method. The username will now be provided down to Updatestatus.java.